# Raspberry Pi 3 not booting

Tags: raspbian, boot-issues, pi-3

Just got my pi today but after I set it up it seems to work properly

```
Ethernet port is lit
Green light is flashing randomly
Red light is static
```

But no HDMI output from my monitor!

Comment: My pendrive is glowing when I connect it!

Comment: Are you using an HDMI monitor or some kind of adapter cable to a non-HDMI monitor?

Comment: Using a hdmi full HD monitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as by "Green light is flashing randomly" you do not mean in a steady, repeated pattern, then it is working.

Put the card in another computer, edit `config.txt` on the first partition (on windows or OSX this may appear to be the only partition) and add:

```
hdmi_safe=1
```

If that works, you can try reducing the subset of things it includes [explained here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#hdmi_safe), since the resolution this way will be low.  For example, it may be that all you actually need is

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

Although this seems a little counter-intuitive, since you aren't actually hotplugging.  It may also be that you need to experiment with `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` settings further down the same page.  Or it may be the `boost` or `ignore_edid` settings, all of which are, again, included with `hdmi_safe`.

Comment: I don't that actually

Comment: If you mean you tried that and it did not work, it is possible the HDMI jack is busted -- try another cable and another TV/monitor if possible.  If the random green flashing never stops, or at least does not slow down a lot after a few minutes, then that is indicative of some other kind of problem, you may want to try re-burning the SD card.

Comment: I'll try it on my TV and inform you!

Comment: It's working now!

Comment: RPi 3B v1.2. hdmi_safe=1 worked fine with the latest rasperian.